# I can't automatically show the latest version of a page uploaded to a server in local browsers

Tags: php, html, cookies

I've tried meta tags, automatic refresh, but it doesn't work. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Put what you tried in the "question", and ask a question in the body of the question. I'm not sure what you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

you meaning this tag

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3">
```

What browsers doesn't work .